# How to actually force a git pull that gets all remote history but keeps the current working files?

Tags: git

Is there a way to force a git pull so that any merge or rebasing conflicts are ignored and the history is the same as the remote, but the current working files are not changed?

I have been looking for something like this for years but have not found it.

If nothing like this exists, why not? It seems to be something that makes a lot of sense to me.

Comment: That is exactly what `git fetch` is.

Comment: @matt You misunderstood the question - I said force, overriding merge or rebasing conflicts.

Comment: @LeGEC No, I know those and they don't do what I asked in the question.

Comment: @paradroid: okay, it looks like you found your answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get remote's commit objects into your local repository use `git fetch`

This fetches the objects from the remote without updating your local branches. What it does update is your remote tracking branches, which are branch pointers that are stored locally but refer to the remote repository. You can see these with `git branch -a`

Example output

```
remotes/origin/main
```

To view the log of this remote `git log remotes/origin/main`. Remember, although this a log of the remote, it can still be out of date if you've not done a fetch recently.

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve but once you're at this point there are a number of things you can then do to manipulate your working copy while offline. Firstly, it's going to get messy if you have locally modified files so **either commit or stash them before proceeding**.

You could

- Merge from `remotes/origin/main` into your local `main` branch - but that would just be the same as if you had performed `git pull`. It may give you more control over the merge though if you want to use options such as `--sqaush` or `--no-commit`
- `git cherry-pick` individual changes from the log of the remote
- Rebase from `remotes/origin/main` - but that would be just the same as if you had performed `git pull --rebase`
- `git checkout -b some-new-branch`, then merge or rebase into that. You can then still use `git checkout` to switch between `some-new-branch` and `main`
- `git checkout -b  some-new-branch` then `git reset remotes/origin/main --hard` will force `some-new-branch` to have the same history as the remote `main`, you can still switch back to your `main` using `git checkout`

Finally `git reset remotes/origin/main` without the `--hard` option appears to be what your question originally asks for but it gives you a pretty weird result. It will update your branch pointer (`main` or `some-new-branch`) but without updating the actual working files. The files that *should* have been updated, but weren't, will now show up as modified. It will be as if you updated, and then manually reverted all the updates without committing. There's rarely a genuine use case for this and it can get messy and confusing.

Finally if you do indeed have to use `git reset` for some reason then `git reflog` is your friend because it shows a log of how your branch pointers got moved, and where they got moved from, so you can move them back again when you realise you screwed up.

Comment: about the `git reset` variants: there also is `git reset --soft`, which keeps the content of the current commit (<- the index actually) in the staging area, so that you can `git commit` straight away and get the same content as the initial commit

Answer (score 1):

Simply overwrite the target branch to point to the same revision as the remote branch using [`git branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch):

```
$ git branch -f <local branch> <remote branch>
```

For example,

```
$ git branch -f master origin/master
```

Note that this does not work if the local branch is currently checked-out in a working tree.

Comment: Is there a way of determining the local and remote branches from the current branch and the currently set remote? So that a standard command or alias can be made?